# There are four of us. We are four. Are both ways correct?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I feel like 'There are four of us' is the correct way to say this, I know that  'we are four' is a translation French and Spanish but is it also correct in English?

Comment: From D. H. Lawrence's [*Quetzalcoatl*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+are+dozens+they+are%22#tbm=bks&q=%22we+are+ten+they+are%22&*) - *And, men, where **we are ten they are a hundred**. We send up one aeroplane, and they come down on us with a cloud of a thousand aeroplanes.*

Comment: ...French can get even more weird... [*Dans ma famille **on est quatre** enfants dont je suis l'aîné.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Dans+ma+famille+on+est+quatre+enfants%22)

Comment: 'Correct', but inherently ambiguous and of a literary style.

Comment: If you're wondering what the ambiguity is, check out A.A. Milne's [*Now We Are Six*](http://www.amazon.com/Now-Deluxe-Winnie-Pooh-Book-ebook/dp/B0013TPY3A/)

Comment: Check out also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Are_Seven . As Edwin Ashworth says, it is 'correct' but would sound odd in everyday modern English.

Comment: There are easily 20 different ways to say it.  No single choice is the "right" one, to the exclusion of others.

Comment: "We Are Four" would be idiomatic and correct, if a bit quaint and stilted, but would connote a pretty specific social class and context. You might imagine someone saying it to the head waiter at a country club, or the leader of an alumni group saying it before embarking on a group hike or something of the source. You would say it with an intent to put on airs. Of course, one would only say it when it is clear from context what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

"There are four of us" is correct.

To ensure "We are four" has the same meaning as the first phrase, 
we can phrase it as "We have four people" or "We are a group of four."